# Could anyone help me to check why my solution receives duplicate results?

Tags: java

> All DNA is composed of a series of nucleotides abbreviated as A, C, G, and T, for example: "ACGAATTCCG". When studying DNA, it is sometimes useful to identify repeated sequences within the DNA.
>
> Write a function to find all the 10-letter-long sequences (substrings) that occur more than once in a DNA molecule.
>
> For example,
>
> Given `s = "AAAAACCCCCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT"`,
>
> Return:
> `["AAAAACCCCC", "CCCCCAAAAA"]`.

My code:

```
public class Solution {
public List<String> findRepeatedDnaSequences(String s) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    if(s == null || s.length() == 0){
        return res;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 10; i++){
        // System.out.print(occurance(s,sub) + ",");
        String sub = s.substring(i, i+10);//endIndex is exclusive
        System.out.print(occurance(s,sub) + ",");
        if(occurance(s,sub) > 1){
            res.add(sub);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private int occurance(String s, String sub){
    int occurTimes = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - sub.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < sub.length(); j++){
            if(sub.charAt(j) != s.charAt(i+j)){
                break;
            }
            if(j == sub.length() - 1){
                occurTimes++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return occurTimes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what output does it produce?

Comment: Why isn't `AACCCCCAAA` an answer? That sequence also occurs twice.

Comment: @Eran Yeah, I did miscount. Thanks.

Comment: @LutzHorn it works. But the output is like [AAAAACCCCC, CCCCCAAAAA, AAAAACCCCC, CCCCCAAAAA], it's duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `findRepeatedDnaSequences` will call `occurance(s,sub)` multiple times for sub-strings that occur multiple times.

You can solve this by keeping the results in a `Set` instead of a `List`.

```
public List<String> findRepeatedDnaSequences(String s) {
    Set<String> res = new HashSet<String>();

    if(s == null || s.length() == 0){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 10; i++){
        String sub = s.substring(i, i+10);
        System.out.print(occurance(s,sub) + ",");
        if(!res.contains(sub) && occurance(s,sub) > 1){
            res.add(sub);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(res);
}
```

Of course, you can get rid of `occurance(s,sub)` and make your code more efficient :

```
public List<String> findRepeatedDnaSequences(String s) {
    Set<String> dup = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> res = new HashSet<String>();

    if(s == null || s.length() == 0){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 10; i++){
        String sub = s.substring(i, i+10);
        if(!dup.add(sub)) { 
            res.add(sub); // add sub to res only if it is already present in dup
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(res);
}
```

Output (for you given input) :

```
[AAAAACCCCC, CCCCCAAAAA]
```

Comment: For OP: If you want to retain the order of first seen, make `res` a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: @Eran thanks for the concrete explanation. I got it now. I tried to avoid using data structure since I am not quite familiar with it, but it seems I has to use Set as least. But will dup.add(sub) in your solution return a boolean value?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the suggestion. For this specific problem I don't need to record the first seen. But I'll keep in mind of LinkedHashSet.

Comment: @ReneWU Javadoc for [`dup.add(sub)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) says: *Returns `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element*

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have ABCABC as your pattern and it's 3 letter occurrences instead of 10. In the loop, it will find the first abc, then call occurrence which prints 2. Then it goes back to the loop, loads the second abc and calls occurrence again. Again it sees the abc, hence showing twice.

If all sequences are 10 digits, you can split the string into chunks of 10, sort it, and count how many are the same.  Otherwise it might be easiest to generate all 10 digit possibilities, though this depends on the size of the dna string. In that case you may need to look into specific string algorithms for processing.